# En Python, al crear una treeview desde una base de datos sqllite3, el campo nombre que tiene espacios me los separa en varias columnas en el treeview

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa de mantenimiento de datos con un treeview, en Python, usando una base de datos SQLLite3.  En la base de datos hay un campo nombre que algunos registros tienen espacios.  Al llevar esos registro al treeview me pone en varias columnas la descripcion separadas por espacios.

El codigo que realizo es:

...

```
     def mostrar():
                    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("presupuesto.db")
                    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
                    registros=Treeview.get_children()
                    for elemento in registros:
                        Treeview.delete(elemento)
                    try:
                        miCursor.execute("SELECT CCodigo, CCNombre FROM Categoria")
                        for row in miCursor:
                        v=row[1]
                        Treeview.insert("",END, text=row[0], values=(v))
                        print(row)
                    except:
                        pass
            
                ################################## Tabla #########
           Treeview=ttk.Treeview(height=10, columns=('#0','#1'))
           Treeview.place(x=0, y=130)
           Treeview.column('#0',width=100)
           Treeview.column('#1',width=400)
           Treeview.heading('#0', text="Codigo", anchor=CENTER)
           Treeview.heading('#1', text="Nombre del Empleado", anchor=CENTER)
...
```

Los datos contenidos en la base de datos esta asi:

```
        ('65', 'con sobreescrito 65')
        ('23', 'veinti tres')
        ('24', 'veinicuatro')
```

En el treeview el nombre del primer registro me lo muestra asi:

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Falto que mostraras como se ve... usa el boton [edit] y agregalo...

Comment: Agrega una coma luego de la v en esta linea: `Treeview.insert("",END, text=row[0], values=(v))`. Es decir, te tiene que quedar como `(v,)`. Sinceramente, no se por que te ponía una palabra por columna (supongo que se debe a como era el comando que Tkinter envió a Tcl). Lo unico que sé es que funcionó...

Comment: Recuerda que el parametro values debe de ser una tupla con todos los valores a pasar. Por ejemplo, para pasar 1, 2 y 3, tiene que ser `values=(1,2,3)`. Lo mismo si es un solo item. Sin la coma, Python no lo interpreta como tupla, por lo que si queres pasarle un solo valor, sería `values=(1,)`.